# nice looking CSS fonts for Mac and Windows

Tags: css, fonts

I see lots of sites that display great fonts that are not images. For example: [The Firebug site](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Happy Cog](http://happycog.com/). There seem to be lots of CSS 'tricks', bits of JavaScript and whatever other trickery employed by various web designers to get the job done (I'm not suggesting either of the aforementioned sites do this).

My question is, what is acceptable in terms of CSS / font practices? Is it still that case that only a core set of common fonts should be used? If not, what are the acceptable / reliable practices to display nice looking fonts, particularly for Mac / Windows consistency?

Comment: Be aware that, while font-embedding is now possible, the font you choose to embed **may** not be licensed for such. You may need to consult a lawyer in your jurisdiction. (This might vary depending on your use-case, commercial/non-commercial, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can embed fonts now. Here's a good place to start: http://www.google.com/webfonts

Answer (score 0):

If you have a font you would like to use, you can use a generator and it will make files that you simply need to include with your website

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator

Simply include something like this in your style sheet:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ArchitectsDaughterRegular';
    src: url('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/ArchitectsDaughter-webfont.svg#ArchitectsDaughterRegular') format('svg');
     font-weight: normal;
     font-style: normal;
}
```

Just make the url point to where you actually have that font. There are also a lot of premade fonts available.